# IN/OUT using STS LDS commands

Tags: arduino

How do I address (reading/writing) the IO registers in lower IO-block (0x00 - 0x63 ) by using the STS  LDS (or equvivalent) instructions only ??

Thanks

Kris

Answer (score 1):

The main question is "where are those registers mapped in memory visible by STS/LDS". And the answer is in the datasheet:

[image]

If you want to change IN/OUT to LDS/STS, you have to add 0x20 offset to the address used in IN/OUT

> 7.5 I/O Memory
>
> The I/O space definition of the ATmega328P is shown in Section  “” on page 275. All ATmega328P I/Os and peripherals are placed
> in the I/O space. All I/O locations may be accessed by the LD/LDS/LDD
> and ST/STS/STD instructions, transferring data between the 32 general
> purpose working registers and the I/O space. I/O registers within the
> address range 0x00 - 0x1F are directly bit-accessible using the SBI
> and CBI instructions. In these registers, the value of single bits can
> be checked by using the SBIS and SBIC instructions. Refer to the
> instruction set section for more details. When using the I/O specific
> commands IN and OUT, the I/O addresses 0x00 - 0x3F must be used. When
> addressing I/O registers as data space using LD and ST instructions,
> 0x20 must be added to these addresses. The ATmega328P is a complex
> microcontroller with more peripheral units than can be supported
> within the 64 location reserved in opcode for the IN and OUT
> instructions. For the extended I/O space from 0x60 - 0xFF in SRAM,
> only the ST/STS/STD and LD/LDS/LDD instructions can be used.For
> compatibility with future devices, reserved bits should be written to
> zero if accessed. Reserved I/O memory addresses should never be
> written.Some of the status flags are cleared by writing a logical one
> to them. Note that, unlike most other AVR®, the CBI and SBI
> instructions will only operate on the specified bit, and can therefore
> be used on registers containing such status flags. The CBI and SBI
> instructions work with registers 0x00 to 0x1F only.The I/O and
> peripherals control registers are explained in later sections.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very, very much.  Kris